# Visual studio 2010 Service Pack 1 Installation Error: Another install of this package is already running

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2010

I am having a very hard time installing Visual Studio 2010 Service Pack 1 on a Windows XP machine. I downloaded and installed a Visual Studio 2010 trial without trouble. But when I downloaded and tried to install Visual Studio Service Pack 1 I got the error message shown below.

Once I got the error, I re-booted (to kill any processes) and opened add/remove programs, which showed that SP1 was installed on my machine. I tried to uninstall SP1 and got the exact same error message that I got during the install!? I then tried to uninstall SP1 using Revo uninstaller and got the same message again.

in my copy of visual studio, intellisense doesn't pick up the @ tag for the razor syntax (SP1 added that support for that syntax)--so I know the installation was unsuccessful

Where can I go from here?

[image]

Comment: Any chance you have Windows set to automatically download and install updates? Where's your VS install from - is it a MSDN ISO? Re @ tag, do you also have MVC 3 installed? I don't know if SP1 includes that but I suspect not, get the web installer from www.asp.net. Good luck!

Comment: perhaps Windows Installer is broke? Try installing/uninstalling some other things to see if you get similar problems. I only say this because I faced similar issues a few years back (not with Visual Studio service packs), and Windows Installer was the culprit.

Comment: @ErOX, but I uninstalled several things yesterday without trouble

Comment: @pelazem : I downloaded visual studio from microsoft via the asp.net tutorial pages (it's a trial copy)

Comment: I don't know for sure, but perhaps you can't install the SP for the trial copy? BTW, which edition of Visual Studio is it? The full 2010, or an express edition?